# How do I know if I'm running python as a shared libary?

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi, apache2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm following the mod_wsgi quick installation guide:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

It states that "Python should preferably be available as a shared library"

How do I check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation explains it at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library

Comment: and official mod_wsgi docs: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library - seems identical, but someone may find it useful